Erro install web apps
These days I was trying to install web apps on my ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS I looked for options that do this but none of them worked, most of them had the same error so I was advised to look for ubuntu support, I found users with the same problem
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/-/issues/2357

is this what you are referring to? Please read [ask] the [edit] accordingly
